# Updating Ternary condition variable angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

I'm fairly new to angular and Im wondering how to achieve the following:

Im using a ternary condition in my variables to switch between two languages without refreshing my page and display items (`ng-repeat`) with the correct titles.

```
{{isEnglish ? item.name_en : item.name_fr}}
```

I have a toggle switching `isEnglish` to `true` or `false`, but the the variables don't update themselves when switching the boolean. Do I need to apply the changes? is there a way to do so?

**language toggle**

```
<a href="" class="fb border_link" ng-click="changelanguage();">
    {{displayLanguage}}
</a>
```

**ng-click function**

```
$scope.changelanguage = function(){
    console.log("changing language");
    console.log($scope.$parent.isEnglish);
    if($scope.selectedLanguage === 'en'){
      $translate.use('fr');
      $scope.$parent.isEnglish = false;
      console.log($scope.$parent.isEnglish);
      $scope.selectedLanguage = 'fr';
      $scope.displayLanguage = 'English';
      console.log("en");
    }
    else{
      $translate.use('en');
      $scope.$parent.isEnglish = true;
      console.log($scope.$parent.isEnglish);
      $scope.selectedLanguage = 'en';
      $scope.displayLanguage = 'Français';
      console.log("fr");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could post more code..

Comment: done, if that help. the ternary condition is inside a ng-repeat div

Comment: @SKYnine: see my second update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making isEnglish an object property like settings.isEnglish. Angular has some issues with raw variables attached to scope.

Comment: @SKYnine first of all I'd strongly suggest not to use $parent and simply use a service to use the same data in two different scopes. Also, isEnglish shouldn't be a variable either, it should be a function (or you could even attempt to do the check right in the view if you want) by returning $scope.selectedLanguage === 'en'. Also the raw variable like selectedLanguage and displayLanguage (arguably to use two different variables) could be in an object just like I said in my answer to avoid any trouble. Give this a try and shoot me back.

Comment: I made an object out of my settings and it started working. I couldn't use a service cause I need scope variable to be dynamic and not only at first load. Anyway, don't understand why it started working (cause I tried the object shape yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

Update 2: Since you're assigning `isEnglish` to the `$scope.$parent` you could have a `$scope`-related problem.

To help troubleshoot I'd use something like [Batarang](https://github.com/angular/batarang) to figure out what the value of `$scope.isEnglish` is for various `$scope`'s.  Alternatively, you could put an `{{ isEnglish }}` binding next to your ternary to confirm that `isEnglish` is being set when `changelanguage` is called.  If it isn't it's going to come down to how your child and isolated scopes are being structured.

---

Update 1: The code you've posted in your question works fine. Here's a working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/R6hfzJyJh8GLPdYXBzVt?p=preview).  Judging from your comment, maybe you have a child scope you're assigning to in your `ng-click`.  Are you doing the assignment directly in the `ng-click` expression or is it done through a method (like in my plunkr)?

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isEnglish = true;

  $scope.toggle = function _toggle() {
    $scope.isEnglish = !$scope.isEnglish;
  };

  $scope.item = {
    name_en: 'en name',
    name_fr: 'fr name'
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">
      Toggle isEnglish
    </button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div>
    isEnglish:
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>{{ isEnglish }}</b>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
    isEnglish ? item.name_en : item.name_fr:
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>{{isEnglish ? item.name_en : item.name_fr}}</b>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

You may need to wrap the toggle in a `$scope.apply` call if it's something like a custom directive that happens outside the digest cycle:

```
// 'scope' is argument in directive link function.
function toggle() {
  scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.isEnglish = !scope.isEnglish;
  });
}
```

Comment: $scope.isEnglish is changed within a ng-click function so digest cycle is already in progress. using $apply() within is triggers error. Everything from the function is working as expected, even the isEnglish toggle. it is just the variable in the html that don't update themselves...

Comment: It's always recommended wrapping the $scope.$apply in a $timeout call so it doesn't enter in conflict with the ongoing $digest flow.

Comment: adding a $timeout indeed prevent the $apply to trigger errors. but the result is the same it doesn't update the variables :(

Comment: the change is done in a function. I've added some code to my question to reflect what I have.